# Empty $_GET params altough QSA flag next to rewrite rule in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've tried various solutions posted here on stackoverflow, none of them seemed to work.

I really wonder what am I missing here, currently .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^register/?$ ./register.php?reference=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I'm getting URL like this:

`domain.com/register/ENIGMA-45`

That's all good, but `$_GET` param don't pass.

I've tried to `print_r($_GET)` and `print($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING]);` both are empty.

```
VirtualHost config:
<VirtualHost 199.99.99.99:82>
    ServerName dot.magicaldomain.com
    ServerAlias www.dot.magicaldomain.com
    DocumentRoot /home/dot/public_html
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dot.magicaldomain.com
    ## User dot # Needed for Cpanel::ApacheConf
    <IfModule mod_userdir.c>
        Userdir disabled
        Userdir enabled dot 
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
        suPHP_UserGroup dot dot
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_disable_suexec.c>
        <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
           SuexecUserGroup dot dot
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
       RUidGid dot dot
    </IfModule>
    CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/dot.magicaldomain.com-bytes_log "%{%s}t %I .\n%{%s}t %O ."
    CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/dot.magicaldomain.com combined
    Options -ExecCGI -Includes
    RemoveHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .plx .ppl .perl
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To capture:

```
domain.com/register/ENIGMA-45
```

You can use this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^register/?([^/]*|)/?$ /register.php?reference=$1 [L]
```

Add this to your `virtualhost`:

```
<Directory "/home/dot/public_html">
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: I've tryed those two rules, both return empty $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING] / $_GET params. :(

Comment: @ProDraz see the update on my answer to capture the URL you have changed.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've made mistake in original post, let me try your update. I'm kinda sure mod_rewrite is ON, because it does rewrite URL's  :P

Comment: @ProDraz yeah I assumed it was off because I was not aware of how you wanted to access it that comment was right before you update the URL hehe

Comment: Well, it still doesn't pass any params :(

Comment: @ProDraz are you trying `domain.com/register/ENIGMA-45` or `domain.com/register/ENIGMA-45/`? And do you have any other rules on the .htaccess?

Comment: Without slash on end. So "domain.com/register/ENIGMA-45"

Comment: OK and do you have any other rules on the .htaccess? I have personally tested the above and it works just fine and both variables dump the result `var_dump($_REQUEST, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);`

Comment: Yeah there is this line "ErrorDocument 404 /404.php"

Comment: Ops misread, mmm, do you have just that one .htaccess? the register.php does print with the empty result?

Comment: Yeah. I do. Hmm I can get request_uri etc., which I can explode and get the reference out, but kinda hoped for direct solution and a way to get $_GET param.

Comment: @ProDraz well GET AND POST should work as well, does $_REQUEST print empty?

Comment: $_REQUEST prints out just as fine. $_GET is empty tough.

Comment: @ProDraz Try this `echo $reference;` and see if it prints ENIGMA-45, if it does means you have register_globals turned on and you should definitively turn it off

Comment: $reference doesn't print. Only thing that prints atm is $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].

Comment: @ProDraz could you post your virtualhost config of your domain?

Comment: Sure. Updated original post.

Comment: @ProDraz oh and yes register folder does not exist right? or does it exist and you have a index.php in there?

Comment: No, there is no register folder :)

Comment: @ProDraz ok try adding the above update to your virtualhost. You may also want to remove your previous `Options` and move the `RemoveHandler` inside of it.

Comment: Works. Thanks for all your efforts.

Comment: @ProDraz great, its possible that the issue was that you just missed the `-MultiViews` I recommend you to set your virtualhost back to what it was and just add those Options to your `.htaccess` to test.